# Setting up a web server on a virtual machine viewable from the host and all other vms running on the host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtual-machines, host, guest

I have set up an Apache web server on a windows 7 ultimate VM guest machine. This machine also has all the software I need to develop server-side scripts (aptana, VS 2008 etc)

The VM is bridged with its own ip address 10.1.10.19 and the apache server is listening on port 80

http://localhost and http://localhost:80 both work on the guest VM - so the apache server is working OK

However, I cannot access the webserver from the host machine (ip address 10.1.10.15) , nor any other VM on the host machine that are also networked with a bridge

How can I set things up so the host and all other VMs on the host can see the web server?

From a browser in the host I have tried
http://10.1.10.19
http://10.1.10.19:80

but with no luck

EDIT: Also accessing 10.1.10.19 from a browser on 10.1.10.19 works also

Comment: What about http://10.1.10.19 from 10.1.10.19 itself ?

Comment: That works...see above

Comment: can  you ping your guest machine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if a firewall rule needs to be created. To test, turn the firewall off entirely (but don't leave it that way).

Comment: Yes, that was it. I opened a hole in firewall restricted to my intranet and it works OK now...thx